# Is it OK to load form input straight into DOMDocument class?

Tags: php, domdocument, sanitization

I built a tool that takes arbitrary HTML, collects all the classes and ids and outputs them back into the page.  I am concerned about security.  I had been using HTML Purifier to filter the input, but I need to support HTML5, which HTML Purifier does not.

This is the gist of the tool:

```
$html=$_POST['html'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//body");

foreach ($elements as $element) { 
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;     
    $output=write_selectors($nodes);
}

function write_selectors($nodes){
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        $node->getAttribute('id');
        .
        .
        .
        $node->getAttribute('class');
        .
        .
        .
    }
    .
    .
    .   
    return 'string containing all classes and ids in the document' 
}
.
.
.
echo htmlentities($output, ENT_QUOTES);
```

My questions are:

It seems like it would be possible for someone to put a string like this into the tool: `'<div '); do_bad_stuff( 'ha_ha_ha'` and that `$doc->loadHTML($html);` would end up saying `$doc->loadHTML('<div '); do_bad_stuff( 'ha_ha_ha');`

It seems like DOMDocument just errors when I try to input funny business like that, but **should I be doing something to protect against malicious inputs?  If not, why not?**

Secondarily, is htmlentities enough to sanitize the output?

Comment: Are you simply retrieving all classes and ids in the document? If yes you are fine. If you are displaying the HTML later you will be having a hard time prevent XSS. Also IIRC you don't need to encode the ids / classnames, because there will only be safe characters allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No,it will never do that. You have $html in a variable and sent that variable directly into the function.
2. Yes, personally I would use htmlspecialchars, but htmlentities is fine to protect you from XSS.

Comment: Thanks!    How come the $html being a variable  sent directly to the function makes it OK?  Also, why do you prefer htmlspecialchars?